# How to fix other element reset to default when using jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element with fixed sidebar with onclick function. When it is clicked at bottom page, the other element as content back to top of page. How I can stop this problem?

Here is my jquery function :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sidebarCollapse").on('click', function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('#sidebar').toggleClass('show-side-nav');
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('#user').toggleClass('d-none');
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('#navbar').toggleClass('show-side-nav');
    });
```

Regards!

Comment: you only need to call `e.stopPropagation();` once - not before every toggle.  Also it's unclear what the problem is - your question doesn't read very well

Comment: @Pete I have called it once even removed it all but it still same

Comment: @Popnoodles I have tried and it same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing it's either a button which will reload the page, or `<a href="#">` which will go to top. You need to use `preventDefault()`. You may not even need `stopPropagation()` in this instance, but if you do you only need it once. Also when you're toggling the same class on two elements, you can select them together.

```
$("#sidebarCollapse").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#sidebar, #navbar').toggleClass('show-side-nav');
  $('#user').toggleClass('d-none');
});
```

Comment: Thanks it work for me using preventDefault(). I am sorry for the question is not clear and I am so sad people downvote my question :(